# GeoJson file not plotting correctly in Altair

Tags: python, geojson, altair

I am trying to create a visualisation in Altair that overlays major rivers onto a map of Europe, and some of the surrounding countries. I used [this website](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/) to download a custom GeoJSON file of Europe, Asia and Africa. I then managed to successfully plot the base map using GeoPandas (imported as gpd) in the following code:

```
custom_world = gpd.read_file('customgeo.json')

base = alt.Chart(custom_world).mark_geoshape(color='lightgrey').encode(   
tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('name:N', title='Country')]
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400
).project(
    scale=400, translate=[100, 550]
)
base
```

[This is the output visualisation of JUST the map data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm4xu.png)

I am using major river GeoJSON data from [this website](http://geojson.xyz/); specifically [this dataset](http://geojson.io/#data=data:text/x-url,https%3A%2F%2Fd2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net%2Fnaturalearth-3.3.0%2Fne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines_scale_rank.geojson). Now, when I attempt to plot this, Altair returns a somewhat correct output, as some of the rivers are plotted as expected, but the map is littered with obscure polygons.

```
majorrivers = gpd.read_file('major-rivers.geojson')

rivers = alt.Chart(majorrivers).mark_geoshape(
filled=False,
strokeWidth=2
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400,
    title = 'Waterways'
).project(
    scale=400, translate=[100, 550]
)
base + rivers
```

[As you can see from the output, something isn't quite right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay50l.png)

It might be worth noting that the problem still persists even when I don't layer the chart and just plot 'rivers'. After numerous Google searches, I still find myself at a loss, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: All of the records in that file are linestrings.  None of them should be drawing polygons.  Have you scanned the file to make sure it is intact?  There are 26,000 features here; I wonder if you have hit some limit in Altair?

Comment: Perhaps you need to filter out the records that aren't in Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I seemed to have fixed it, and want to share in case someone comes across this issue too.

It might have been important to note that I am using a Jupyter Notebook to create this visualisation. I just so happened to open another Notebook with a known working Altair visualisation and found the same obscure polygons present. To fix it, I closed JupyterLab, opened it back up and ran all cells in the Notebook.

[Using the same code, this seemed to produce the desired output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhoE4.png)